# Calling SpeechAPI for text to speech on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-speech-api

I have the following very basic TTS code running on my local server

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
...
SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
reader.Speak("This is a test");
```

This code has a dependency on System.Speech for which I have added a Reference in my VS 2015 project.
Works fine but from what I have read and from trying it I know this will not work when the code is hosted on Azure.
I have read several posts on SO querying if it is actually possible to do TTS on azure.  Certainly 2 yrs ago it did not appear to be possible. [How to get System.Speech on windows azure websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230426/how-to-get-system-speech-on-windows-azure-websites)

All roads seem to lead to the Microsoft Speech API
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/marketplace/partners/speechapis/speechapis/
I have signed up and have gotten my private and sec keys for calling into this API.
However my question is this.  How do I actually call the SpeechAPI?  What do I have to change in the simple code example above so that this will work when running on azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speech API you referred to at the Azure marketplace is part of an AI Microsoft project called [ProjectOxford](https://www.projectoxford.ai/) which offers an array of APIs for computer vision, speech and language.

These are all RESTful APIs, meaning that you will be constructing HTTP requests to send to a hosted online service in the cloud.
The speech-to-text documentation is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613445.aspx) and you can find sample code for various clients on github. Specifically for C# you can see some code in [this sample project](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Speech/TextToSpeech/Samples-Http/CSharp).

Please note that ProjectOxford is still in preview (Beta). Additional support for using these APIs can be found on the [ProjectOxford MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=mlapi).

But just to give you an idea of how your program will look like (taken from the above code sample on github):

```
        AccessTokenInfo token;

        // Note: Sign up at http://www.projectoxford.ai for the client credentials.
        Authentication auth = new Authentication("Your ClientId goes here", "Your Client Secret goes here");

        ... 

        token = auth.GetAccessToken();

        ...

        string requestUri = "https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize";

        var cortana = new Synthesize(new Synthesize.InputOptions()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(requestUri),
            // Text to be spoken.
            Text = "Hi, how are you doing?",
            VoiceType = Gender.Female,
            // Refer to the documentation for complete list of supported locales.
            Locale = "en-US",
            // You can also customize the output voice. Refer to the documentation to view the different
            // voices that the TTS service can output.
            VoiceName = "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, ZiraRUS)",
            // Service can return audio in different output format. 
            OutputFormat = AudioOutputFormat.Riff16Khz16BitMonoPcm,
            AuthorizationToken = "Bearer " + token.access_token,
        });

        cortana.OnAudioAvailable += PlayAudio;
        cortana.OnError += ErrorHandler;
        cortana.Speak(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise it was still in Beta.  Having read the pricing on Azure website it would cost us almost $1Mil for the number of speech requests we currently process ( 250 Mil per annum,  costs us about 50K in AWS EC2 instances to provide the same service ) So I tried to verify if I had read the pricing information correctly,  3 emails from 3 different people later,  I find myself directed back to their azure pricing page ,,  sorry,  "we are not sure".  Does not look like Azure is going to fly for our particular use case :(

Comment: Which pricing website are you referring to? 
ProjectOxford pricing can be found here: https://www.projectoxford.ai/pricing

Comment: Note due to it being in preview, pricing is subject to change for these APIs. Anyway, if you are using other methods to process these on EC2 instances and considering a move to Azure, its worth comparing to Azure VMs pricing as well here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ That would be a more "apples" to "apples" comparison